# How do i reverse a string in SQL Server without using reverse function?

Tags: sql-server, string, reverse

I have a string 'TRADITIONAL'.
I want to reverse the order of the characters and the result should be 'LANOITIDART'.
How is it achievable in SQL server, without using the reverse() function?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Is this a homework question? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Why can't/won't use use the `REVERSE` function? Why not use the tool explicitly designed to do what you're asking?

Comment: It's hideously inefficient to do this without `REVERSE` -- which is a good reason to justify the existence of `REVERSE`. If this is just for fun/homework it's one thing, if you believe there's an actual operational reason not to use it that would be more interesting.

Comment: Although it sounds like a duplicate question, the linked question that this one is flagged as a duplicate to, is not actually a duplicate. This questioner wanted to turn 'TRADITIONAL' into 'LANOITIDART'. The other questioner wanted to turn 'A Student' into 'Student A'. That's entirely different. For this question, the answer given below by Rishi is actually correct. (No idea at all though, why REVERSE couldn't just be used).

Comment: Was just an out of the box question, if we can do anything such using some string functions. You might consider a homework.!

Answer (score 1):

You may create following function -

```
CREATE function StringReverse(@inputstring varchar(max))  
returns varchar(max)   
AS  
BEGIN  
  DECLARE @i int,   
          @Result varchar(max)  
  SET @Result=''  
  SET @i = 1  
  WHILE @i <= LEN(@inputstring)  
  BEGIN  
    SET @Result = SUBSTRING(@inputstring,@i,1) + @Result  
    SET @i=@i + 1  
  END  
  RETURN @Result 
END
```

Execution of function -

`select dbo.StringReverse('xyz123abc')`

Comment: That'll be awfully show though. It contains a `WHILE` and scalar functions can be very slow performers by themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the info.Is there any way we can do this in a line of code?

Comment: @SumanthDixit: Newlines aren't significant in T-SQL, so you can squash it all on one line if you desire. If you mean "is there a simple scalar expression without `REVERSE`", then no -- that's why there's `REVERSE`. T-SQL is not comparable to modern programming languages; its string manipulation can be singled out as a particular weakness.